# Using the same class library in windows application and web service

Tags: winforms, web-services, class

I working with:

Class Library: Model.dll

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace root
{
    public class Customer
    {
        private int _Id;

        public int Id
        {
            get { return _Id; }
            set { _Id = value; }
        }

        private string _Name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set { _Name = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

---

ASP.NET Web Service with reference to Model.dll so i can use in web method:

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld(root.Customer customer) {
   return "Hello World";
}
```

---

Windows Application with reference to both Model.dll and Web Service (1).

```
root.Customer newCustomer = new Customer();
newCustomer.Id = 1;
newCustomer.Name = "Name";

ws.Service ws = new root.ws.Service();
ws.HelloWorld(newCustomer);
              ^ problem here
```

**Error: Argument '1': cannot convert from 'root.Customer' to 'root.ws.Customer'**

---

(1) Right click -> And Web Reference -> Web services in this solution -> Click Service.asmx ->
Enter Web reference name: **ws** -> Click Add reference

---

**Updated:** I can change line in generated Reference.cs file from

```
public string HelloWorld(Customer customer)
```

to

```
public string HelloWorld(root.Customer customer)
```

So function will be looking for real model instead of proxy object, but is not real answer.
I don't event think about editing this file after each web reference update.
How to force this for using real model?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that reusing types in automatically generated ASMX proxies is impossible.

There are three options.

1) write your own code generator that will act like the `wsdl.exe` i.e. build a proxy of your web service but reusing your specified types

(rather difficult)

2) write your own code rewriter that will rewrite proxies generated automatically to use your own types. You'd invoke such rewriter each time after you build up your reference to the web service

(still tedious)

3) switch to WCF web services. a WCF service on a basicHttpBinding is semantically equivalent to a ASMX web service (uses the same communication protocol based on http + soap) but the WCF service metadata contain more information about types so that the proxy generator is able to "reuse types from referenced assemblies".

(suggested approach)

Comment: +1. See also [WCF the Manual Way… the Right Way](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?QuickID=0809101).

Answer (score 0):

If you switch away from asmx and start using WCF's svc model, you can share a library between the server and client without much fuss at all.  If that is an option, there are plenty of resources to help you out with WCF online.